# Formatter at cursive IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, ide, cursive

Is there any way to pretty format code in cursive?

For example I have inline code:

```
(reduce (fn [acc [key value]] (apply str acc (repeat (read-string key) value))) "" (apply assoc {} data))
```

Is there any way to formatting in cursive in new lines with `⌥⌘L` ? Any Advice, guides articles would help. Thx!

Comment: My guess here is, tthat this is the exact result you will get from using the formatter. This is also what e.g. `cljfmt` gives you.  There are no set rules to format this (at least that i know of). Some folks want a line break inside the fn, some want the first argument in the first line - others don't.  And then all break down, if you just have some short code like `(reduce + 42 xs)`.

Comment: Code formatting in Cursive only does the indentation for you.  You need to determine where to add in newlines.

Comment: @cfrick is there any way to integrate cljfmt to cursive?

Comment: @RuslanGlaznyov Can't say - i don't use it.